# How to read radio button is checked or not in Javascript, if radio button is declared via Javascript and not by HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function buildQuiz(currentIndex) {

  if (currentIndex === 0) {
    quiz.forEach((item, index) => {
      outputAnswers = [];
      for (option in item.option) {
        outputAnswers.push(
          `<label> <input type="radio" name="question${index}" value="${option}">
                                        ${item.option[option]} </label><br>`
        );
      }

      // add this question and its answers to the output
      output.push(
        `<div class="slide${index}">
           <div class="question"> ${item.question} </div>
           <div class="answers"> ${outputAnswers.join("")} </div>
         </div>`
      );
    });
  }
```

I am creating quiz application in JavaScript and I have added "div" one by one by looping and, individual "div" also contains a question and its option with radio button. I am struggling with reading the radio button that which radio button is actually checked?

Comment: can you provide the data for the variable quiz or dummy data... if possible provide the working snippet else just the data for the variable quiz...

Comment: are you using jquery here?? What're libraries are you using??

Comment: https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/~000736376/a4/

Comment: No I'm not using jQuery  Kenry Sanchez

Comment: @Kenry - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Did you get this far: document.querySelector('input[name="question0"]:checked').value;

Comment: @JasonB I did it with your way thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to the radio buttons and register a click/change handler:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".your-class")
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // `e.target` will point to the radio button clicked
  });
```

Now, you can get the radio button which was clicked and then observe its `name` property to exactly identify it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this way:**

```
if(your_radio.checked){
  // Do something
}
else if(!your_radio.checked){
  // Do something
}
```